# How to convert to Nellymoser 16kHz with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, flv

I am trying to do with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i Fairytale.mp3 -acodec nellymoser -ar 16000 -ac 1 output.flv
```

and get an error

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'Fairytale.mp3':
  Duration: 00:03:03.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 96 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 96 kb/s
[nellymoser @ 0x7fa8c0]flv does not support that sample rate, choose from (44100, 22050, 11025).
Output #0, flv, to 'output.flv':
    Stream #0.0: Audio: nellymoser, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)
```

I know definitely, that FLV+Nellymoser do supprt 16 KHz, but it should be set as separate format with zeros in rate field (Arbitrary Nellymoser is format no. 6, while 16kHz is 4).

Is it possible to set sound resampling parameters separately from header fill-in in ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2):

@Dims, contrary to what you believe you know, ffmpeg is telling you the ONLY sampling rates it accepts for encoding nellymoser, that certainly does not include 16K. Please refer to the documentation for Nellymoser and you will see that the confirmed hard coded rates are exactly what the log message is telling you

Comment: Answers, by the way, do not @notify the posters of other answers, FYI